# Muddled Webmasters naming

Tags: bug, design

The presented naming on the [main site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) is muddled:  sometimes it's `ProWebmasters` (e.g. in the header), and sometimes it's just `Webmasters` (e.g. in the search prompt, and in the navigation menu).

Comment: Related: [Why “Pro” in “Pro Webmasters”](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-pro-in-pro-webmasters)