# Does ProWebmasters Need to rebrand?

Tags: discussion

I was chatting with some people you might call "influencers" in SEO recently.

When I mentioned how stoked I was on how we've been doing here on Pro Webmasters lately, replies echoed "Old school, love it!!"

If I'm being honest, 90% of regulars here know more about Search Engine Optimization than *anyone* that might identify as "influencers" within the SEO community.

And it's a G%^ D%$N shame.

But I wonder if part of the reason our site is not as popular/known anymore is that it is perceived by newer "SEOs" as being less relevant for up-to-date stuff.

I'm fine with not being *cool* in fact I *prefer* it in most cases, but there's a lot of knowledge here that doesn't get the credit it deserves.

Personally, I love this site for what it is. We blend SEO, with Systems Administration, to even backend stuff that I'm often inclined to flag to go to Server Fault but don't because I'm proud that we handle it here.

Are people still becoming "webmasters" tho?

How do we best ensure the longevity of this site?

Food for thought. Not like we have much control over such a thing.

But just saying I own `serpoverflow.com` and I'm happy to part with it.

Unfortunately we're stuck on a subdomain......*forever*.......

Comment: There are some great observations here! I do agree that "Pro Webmasters" has a very old-school ring to it. You're right that it's a term that's not really used a lot anymore. Just to throw a random idea into the hat for the sake of brainstorming: "Website Administration Stack Exchange".

Comment: Appreciate the support, Max. My initial brain dump: "Website Administration", in my view, retains the ambiguity that may plague us. In my opinion, while we once had a broad term "Webmasters" to define a group you'd go to for a variety of things, as you've agreed...we don't use it anymore. I think by becoming more specific, we shed that ambiguity whilst bolstering _all_ related SE sites around us. ServerFault and WordPress SE come top of mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "becoming more specific?"

Comment: `seo.stackexchange.com` vs `webmasters.stackexchange.com`

Comment: While SEO is our biggest tag, it is just one of the topics we cover. I don't think we'd want to focus our name just on that. I personally hate the acronym SERP.  I usually replace it with "search results" when I edit posts.

Comment: It's just an example dude @StephenOstermiller you get what I mean

Comment: Stack Overflow (the company) stopped giving sites their own domain names and uses subdomains because the overhead was less manageable for them. I don't think we would be be allowed to use a domain name.

Comment: Forget about the domain, that's a forgone conclusion. I'm attempting to help solve a clear problem.

Comment: I've never like the "pro" in "Pro Webmasters."  See [Why "Pro" in "Pro Webmasters"](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-pro-in-pro-webmasters). I'd be happy rebranding our site to something like "Website Administration", but I worry that "websites.stackexchange.com" would be too ambiguous.  I'd want to keep the webmasters subdomain but change the logo and page titles if we did that.

Comment: To me, "webmasters" is outdated because it isn't a viable career option. Companies don't hire a webmaster.  They either hire teams of specialists to build a website or contract with a company for their website. Nobody has "webmaster" as their job title.  "Website Administration" describes the process rather than career and doesn't feel outdated to me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller To be honest, "Website Administration Stack Exchange" has been ringing in my head since I threw it out there yesterday. I was hoping others would feel the same way.

Comment: @MikeCiffone I get what you mean now by being more specific with the brand, I just personally struggle to think of a good candidate name that encompasses the breadth of this SE. I'm open to ideas!

Comment: I would also support widening the name and scope to include web site administration.  I have always not liked the term "webmaster" and tend to use the term "webtech".

Comment: I think we need a N00bWebmasters to complement Pro.

Comment: websites.stackexchange.com? In all reality that's accurate.

Comment: and we make sure the new logo is sick. Also might spruce up the header like Stack Overflow's, which looks super clean

Comment: @MikeCiffone Some quick concepts. These are community property, any SE member should feel free to download, edit, remix. Would love to get others making concepts too. The more ideas the merrier! https://www.dropbox.com/s/ki1frgr5vxexnhq/webmasters-logo.ai?dl=0

Comment: I say we iterate on the second one. The first looks too much like my modem (Surfboard), and I think using the same logo would be counterproductive to rebranding.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Got an artboard going...what if we don't need to reinvent the wheel? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qDPiy6fhKZPd3gQ6JqzGI4ZWICqAKDmK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Chiming in from another site: it's very unlikely you're going to be able to get your logo changed, and perhaps less likely that Stack Exchange will use a logo suggested by the community. Plenty of other sites have suggested logos, and of those that _did_ get a custom design afterwards (since 2014), none of them have got their community design. The company doesn't use community designs, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks for the tip. That's disappointing that communities don't have a say in their identity.

Comment: @MikeCiffone They somewhat do: often the designers ask for suggestions when they're first making a site design. I think there's a liability issue if they use other people's ideas, and it turned out that those ideas didn't “belong” to the person who suggested them. And some sites _have_ got rebrands, like Programmers – but that took a very long time (and I think it might only have been Programmers).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 gotcha

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks for chiming in. Out of curiosity how did this thread come to your attention?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The “Hot Meta Posts” section of the sidebar. I think I end up on this site four or five times a year, just from poking around the 'net.

Comment: "But I wonder if part of the reason our site is not as popular/known anymore is that it is perceived by newer "SEOs" as being less relevant for up-to-date stuff." I do hope that this Q&A site is not only for "SEO" questions, but everything related to running a website. So in that case, various groups of people will come and go depending on their interests and the values they perceive out of this website. You can imagine later a wave about "Web3" topics for example.