# Goodbye "Pro Webmasters". Hello, "Webmasters!"

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**TL;DR:  Our site's name is changing soon from "Pro Webmasters" to just "Webmasters".**

Recently we had a discussion [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/the-great-rebranding-of-prowebmasters-stack-exchange) regarding rebranding our site with a different name. Although we didn't reach a clear  consensus on a *new* name, it did become clear that at a minimum "Pro" should be dropped from "Pro Webmasters", since "Webmaster" is no longer a commonly used professional title.

So soon you may notice that our banner (i.e., graphics) and other places on the site that previously stated "Pro Webmasters" will now just be "Webmasters" - thanks to the help of our Community Managers (big thanks to [Catija](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/88057/catija) and [SpencerG](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/122410/spencerg))! This may be done in stages though, so there's no need to report for a while that you're still seeing the "Pro" here or there (and remember to clear your browser cache, Webmasters!) :-) When the magical process is complete, I'll update this with the `status-completed` tag.

There's also text in various places on the site that may change to reflect this too, such as the description on the Home page. If that requires more changes than just removing the "Pro", we may bring that up as a separate discussion so that the community can have input on that too.

Note this doesn't mean that we've entirely closed the door on renaming the site to another name, however it became evident as our wise mod/monk John Conde put it: `The "Pro" in "Pro Webmasters" has to go`. After these changes are completed, we can revisit renaming the site again further down the road with another rebranding/renaming discussion. So if you happen to think of an *awesome* new name that we should consider for later, jot it down…or bring it up in our chat room.

And with that I say:  Welcome to **Webmasters!**

Comment: My upvote does not do this justice. This emoji is more how I feel ヽ(＾Д＾)ﾉ

Comment: Credit should go to you too for having the courage to ask [Why "Pro" in "Pro Webmasters"](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-pro-in-pro-webmasters) so early on, and to Max for having the fortitude to officially open the discussion that led to this change. Kudos guys!

Comment: @dan Thanks, but credit goes to Mike for [opening the discussion](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/the-great-rebranding-of-prowebmasters-stack-exchange), I just put the official seal on it.

Comment: Yes, thanks should also go out to Mike, and everyone who participated in that discussion.

Comment: This is awesome news! Appreciate it Max. Looks like the change has already taken affect. This was definitely the best course of action given the complexity and nuance of the situation.

Comment: Indeed, some of the updates have already been applied, and others are still being worked on.

Comment: It appears this has been completed, so the `status-completed` tag was added.